# Can I reset the "elapsed" reference in loguru

Tags: python, loguru

I am using loguru, and when I start a new test or rerun a test, I remove the old file-handler and add a new one to separate logs per-run and reflect the new start time.  However, the logger's elapsed time in the stream-handler and the file-handler both reflect the original elapsed reference.

Elapsed after several tests:

[image]

Is there a way to reset this reference as-needed?

loguru is so easy at first, but it's such a pain to workaround things that seem so simple, when you start to dive in.

Thanks in advance.

---

I tried removing and replacing both my stream-handler and file-handler.  I hoped this may reset the elapsed reference, but it didn't help.

I searched google and found nothing besides how to format the elapsed time.

I tried removing the logger and re-importing it, but no help

Attempted deleting the logger:
[image]

```
import sys
import time

from loguru import logger

logger.remove(0)
logger.add(sys.stderr, format='<light-black>{elapsed}</> | <cyan>{level:8}</> <light-cyan>|</> <level>{message}</>')
logger.info('test')
time.sleep(1)
logger.info('test')

del logger
from loguru import logger

logger.remove(0)
logger.add(sys.stderr, format='<light-black>{elapsed}</> | <cyan>{level:8}</> <light-cyan>|</> <level>{message}</>')
logger.info('test')
time.sleep(1)
logger.info('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the loguru github issues and found a solution. I'm surprised it didn't show up in my Google searches.

[How to reset the elapsed time?](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru/issues/867#issuecomment-1537944764)

> The best solution would be to add your own argument to the record.

```
import sys
import time
from loguru import logger
from datetime import timedelta

class LauncherTime:
    def __init__(self):
        self._start = time.time()

    def reset(self):
        self._start = time.time()

    @property
    def elapsed(self):
        return timedelta(seconds=time.time() - self._start)

launcher_time = LauncherTime()

logger.configure(
    extra={"launcher_time": launcher_time},
    handlers=[{"sink": sys.stderr, "format": "[{extra[launcher_time].elapsed}] {message}"}],
)

def f():
    launcher_time.reset()
    logger.info("Entering function")
    time.sleep(1)
    logger.info("Leaving function")

for _ in range(100):
    f()
```

Comment: Since this doesn't answer the question whatsoever, it would be recommended to close the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I hope this helps.  I read the help center for more information.  I'm providing context and quoting the provided solution in case the link dies.  Is this better?